# Wordpress Multisite Setup - New Site Dashboard Error

Tags: wordpress

I have setup multi site on my website with following configs:

wp-config.php

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have added a new site http://site1.mysite.com

When I am trying to access its dashboard from Network Dash board after creating the site am getting following error:

I have visited wordpress blog also but unable to find the exact solution.

Can anybody help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: What is the error? And do yourself a favour and look in the error.log file.It will save you much time solving the error.

Comment: No error log generated. Do I have to write .htaccess in the sobdomain folder? If yes then what should I have to write?

Comment: Error is accessing the page: http://www.site1.mysite.com/wp-admin/ . But when am accessing http://www.site1.mysite.com/ its showing index of ... and listing the cgi-bin folder.

Comment: Is anybody there to help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by editing sub-domain in cPanel.
Just change the sub-domain Document Root from /public_html/site1 to /public_html and clear the Redirection.